# Javascript variables from HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to write a program that draws a triangle from the points given in the form that I have created. I know that the drawing functions I have wrote are working, as I have tested and drawn triangles by inserting the parameters by hand, however when I attempted to draw the triangle from the values in the fields, my drawLine2 function produces a different result than when I insert the values by hand. I was wondering if I had done something incorrect when assigning the values of the form to the Javascript variables. Any help at all would be great.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function updateForm() {
  var firstx = document.getElementById("firstx").value;
  var firsty = document.getElementById("firsty").value;
  var secondx = document.getElementById("secondx").value;
  var secondy = document.getElementById("secondy").value;
  var thirdx = document.getElementById("thirdx").value;
  var thirdy = document.getElementById("thirdy").value;
  drawLine2(firstx, firsty, secondx, secondy);
  drawLine2(secondx, secondy, thirdx, thirdy);
  drawLine2(thirdx, thirdy, firstx, firsty);
}


function drawLine2(orx, ory, dx, dy) {
  var offsetx = 1;
  if (orx - dx > 0) {
    offsetx = -1;
  }
  var offsety = 1;
  if (ory - dy > 0) {
    offsety = -1;
  }
  drawLine(Math.abs(orx - dx), Math.abs(ory - dy), offsetx, offsety, orx, ory);
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, ox, oy, orx, ory) {
  var x0 = 0;
  var y0 = 0;
  var dy = y1 - y0;
  var dx = x1 - x0;
  var d = dy - (dx * 0.5);
  var x = x0;
  var y = y0;
  if (Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)) {
    while (y < y1) {
      drawPixel(x, y, ox, oy, orx, ory);
      y = y + 1;
      if (d < 0) {
        d = d + dx;
      } else {
        x = x + 1;
        d = d + dx - dy;
      }
    }
  } else {
    while (x < x1) {
      drawPixel(x, y, ox, oy, orx, ory);
      x = x + 1;
      if (d < 0) {
        d = d + dy;
      } else {
        y = y + 1;
        d = d + dy - dx;
      }
    }
  }
}


function drawPixel(x, y, ox, oy, orx, ory) {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect((ox * x) + orx, (oy * y) + ory, 1, 1);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
  First X: <input type="number" max="500" min="0" id="firstx" value="250">
  <br> First Y: <input type="number" max="500" min="0" id="firsty" value="250">
  <br> Second X: <input type="number" max="500" min="0" id="secondx" value="0 ">
  <br> Second Y: <input type="number " max="500 " min="0 " id="secondy" value="0 ">
  <br> Third X: <input type="number " max="500 " min="0 " id="thirdx" value="0 ">
  <br> Third Y: <input type="number " max="500 " min="0 " id="thirdy" value="250 ">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="updateForm()" value="Submit ">
</form>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500 " height="500 " style="border:1px solid #000000; ">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively you're working with strings. Parse to `int`, or whatever number type makes the most sense.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function updateForm() {
  var firstx = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstx").value, 10);
  var firsty = parseInt(document.getElementById("firsty").value, 10);
  var secondx = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondx").value, 10);
  var secondy = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondy").value, 10);
  var thirdx = parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdx").value, 10);
  var thirdy = parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdy").value, 10);
  drawLine2(firstx, firsty, secondx, secondy);
  drawLine2(secondx, secondy, thirdx, thirdy);
  drawLine2(thirdx, thirdy, firstx, firsty);
}


function drawLine2(orx, ory, dx, dy) {
  var offsetx = 1;
  if (orx - dx > 0) {
    offsetx = -1;
  }
  var offsety = 1;
  if (ory - dy > 0) {
    offsety = -1;
  }
  drawLine(Math.abs(orx - dx), Math.abs(ory - dy), offsetx, offsety, orx, ory);
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, ox, oy, orx, ory) {
  var x0 = 0;
  var y0 = 0;
  var dy = y1 - y0;
  var dx = x1 - x0;
  var d = dy - (dx * 0.5);
  var x = x0;
  var y = y0;
  if (Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)) {
    while (y < y1) {
      drawPixel(x, y, ox, oy, orx, ory);
      y = y + 1;
      if (d < 0) {
        d = d + dx;
      } else {
        x = x + 1;
        d = d + dx - dy;
      }
    }
  } else {
    while (x < x1) {
      drawPixel(x, y, ox, oy, orx, ory);
      x = x + 1;
      if (d < 0) {
        d = d + dy;
      } else {
        y = y + 1;
        d = d + dy - dx;
      }
    }
  }
}


function drawPixel(x, y, ox, oy, orx, ory) {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect((ox * x) + orx, (oy * y) + ory, 1, 1);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
  First X: <input type="number" max="500" min="0" id="firstx" value="250">
  <br> First Y: <input type="number" max="500" min="0" id="firsty" value="250">
  <br> Second X: <input type="number" max="500" min="0" id="secondx" value="0 ">
  <br> Second Y: <input type="number " max="500 " min="0 " id="secondy" value="0 ">
  <br> Third X: <input type="number " max="500 " min="0 " id="thirdx" value="0 ">
  <br> Third Y: <input type="number " max="500 " min="0 " id="thirdy" value="250 ">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="updateForm()" value="Submit ">
</form>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500 " height="500 " style="border:1px solid #000000; ">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem! Its my first time using Javascript or HTML so thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem don't forget to upvote and accept the answer (the up arrow and tick respectively)